SAPUI5 Problem with singlePlanningCalendar mouseover
with sap ui version 1.71.53 it was possible to display information on mouseover:
this.getView().byId("idPC2").addEventDelegate({
                onmouseover: function (oEvent) {
                    if (oEvent.target.classList.contains("sapUiCalendarApp")) {
                        if (oEvent.srcControl) {
                            var displayText = oEvent.srcControl.getTitle() + " " + oEvent.srcControl.getText() + " (" + oEvent.srcControl.getDescription() +
                            ")";

so i could display the whole Title, Text and Description on mouseover
now with 1.124.0 i get the error that srcControl getTitle(), getText() and getDescription() are no functions.
it seems like srcControl is no longer the appointment but the whole calendar.
I debugged and could not find any relation to the appointment.
so how can i display the appointment details on mouseover ?
